# If functions are values why can't callback functions be a variable?

Tags: javascript, callback

In functional programming functions are values.  So if a function is a value why can't I use a variable as a callback function?

`function myFunction() {}` works as a callback.

`myFunction = function() {}` doesn't work as a callback.

The test code below doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

```js
'use strict';
 
var myFunction;
 
window.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
 
myFunction = function() {
  console.log('clicked');
}
```

```html
<button id="click">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the part where the variable is assigned to the function. This happens later then then the use with the event listener. At the time where the event listener get the variable, the value of the variable is `undefined`.

It works properly if you change the assignment and the use of the variable.

[Function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) gets hoisted, whereas assignments stay in place.

```js
'use strict';
 
var myFunction;

myFunction = function() {
    console.log('clicked');
}

window.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```html
<button id="click">click</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I assumed that myFunction was hoisted.  I'll watch for that next time!